# shortcut key for traverse command history in a Mathematica session in a terminal?

Tags: command-line

I wonder what is the shortcut key for traverse command history (i.e. retrieve last, last last, ..., commands) in a Mathematica session in a terminal?

If I hit the up/down arrow or pageup/pagedown, it will only show some incomprehensible codings of the keys.

My OS is Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I use the command line kernel quite often and use it in conjunction with [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/). This allows for history, command line completion, and command line editing. A convenient addition - all one would desire.

Comment: very nice! Do you happen to know how to get EditIn working again? In 5.2 it still worked.

Comment: @RolfMertig, no, not really, I'd have to dig in really deep and find that. See if rlwrap helps you if not, I'll try to find out what happened to EditIn happened.

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica does not use [readline](http://www.gnu.org/software/readline/) on Linux so it's simply not possible to do this.  [You might Google for readline based command line interfaces to Mathematica.](http://robotics.caltech.edu/~radford/jmath/)

---

That said, I strongly recommend not to use the command line interface unless you simply have no means of using the front end (e.g. working on a remote server through a slow network that makes X forwarding inconvenient).  Despite what you might read on Unix forums, command lines are not always more convenient than a well designed graphical interface.  It is impossible to be nearly as productive with any sort of command line as a proper notebook interface *when using Mathematica or similar systems*.  And note that a notebook interface is an extension of the command line, with a superset of a command line's functionality.

Comment: I disagree. For certain problemd the command line very much superior (e.g. faster restart, no trouble with the Frontend).

Comment: (strange 5 minute edit rule for comments...): @Szabalocs:   Also Wolfram Workbench (Eclipse) is just the command line, resurrected: no problem with multiple undo, history, CVS, svn, Mercurial, git, all there. How to do this in the standard FrontEnd? I use all UI's to Mathematica: FrontEnd, command line, Wolfram Workbench. Also: until Mathematica 3.0 most programmers did not use the FrontEnd.

Comment: Does the front end have a way to scroll through command history?  I know about Ctrl+L, but that's not the same as the up key in the command-line.

Comment: @AndrewMacFie No, but at least to display them is just a one-liner   FlipView@Reverse@DownValues@In

Comment: JMath was made for Mathematica 5.2.
It seems no trivial to get it to compile.